# GNSSサンプルアプリケーション open errorについて

Tags: spresense

Spresense SDKチュートリアルに従って
定義済みコンフィグレーションを使用して設定してmakeしましたが、
open関数がエラーで返ってしまい測位に至りません。

簡単な設定を見落としていると思うのですが、
行き詰ってしまいましたので質問させてください。

gnssコマンド実行時のエラーメッセージ

```
　open error:-1
```

buildに使用したコマンドは以下です。

```
cd spresense/sdk
tools/config.py --kernel release
tools/config.py examples/gnss
make buildkernel
make
```

nuttx.spkの書込みは成功しているようです。

初歩的な質問ですみませんが、ご教示お願い致します。

Answer (score 2):

ちょっと当てずっぽうで恐縮ですが、
ブートローダーが正常にインストールされていない可能性があります。
最新のものもしくはSDKのバージョンに合ったものをインストールしたかどうかを
確認してみてください。
再度インストールしても良いかと思います。

Answer (score 0):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。

お問い合わせ頂いたgnssサンプルアプリケーション実行時のエラーについてですが、
GNSSのファームウェアがSpresense基板に正しくインストールされていない事が原因として考えられます。
GNSSのファームウェアはSpresense SDKのバージョンに合わせてアップデートいただく必要があり、
アップデート頂かないと正しく動作致しません。

下記ページの手順を参考にファームウェアのインストールをお試しください。
[https://developer.sony.com/ja/develop/spresense/developer-tools/get-started-using-nuttx/set-up-the-nuttx-environment#*spresense*%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9C%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%B8%E3%81%AE%E3%83%96%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%80%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB](https://developer.sony.com/ja/develop/spresense/developer-tools/get-started-using-nuttx/set-up-the-nuttx-environment#_spresense_%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9C%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%B8%E3%81%AE%E3%83%96%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%80%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB)

今後ともSPRESENSEをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

SPRESENSEサポートチーム